# Remove or Delete existing Websphere Application Server's profile

Tags: java, websphere

I want to remove Websphere Application Server profile and its service from my machine.

In Profile management tool i could see only option to create a profile and there is no option to delete existing profile

so how to delete and remove service of existing profile?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. First list out all profiles in your environment by using
   **manageprofiles** command.

   ```
   ex:WAS_Home/bin/manageprofiles.bat -listProfiles
   ```
2. Stop all servers which are related to that profile.
3. Stop node agents, dmgr process which are related to that profiles.
4. Follow the syntax to delete profile using **manageprofiles** command
        Syntax:

   ```
   WAS_Rootbin/manageprofiles.bat  -delete -profileName <profile_name>
   ```

   manage profiles command has more options like *username,password.*
5. After deleting profiles check list of profiles using **manageprofiles**
   command.

   ```
   manageprofiles.bat -listProfiles
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I have deleted created profile using

> manageProfiles.bat

Find below command to delete profile is

```
manageprofiles -delete -profileName <YourProfileName>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your operating system. Try using **manageprofiles.bat** for Windows or **manageprofiles.sh** for UNIX/Linux located at **was_install_dir\bin\**

You can read how to delete profiles using this command [here](http://akhilesh-humbe.blogspot.ru/2013/06/how-to-delete-websphere-application.html).

Or use `manageprofiles.sh -help`

Answer (score 0):

manageprofiles.sh -delete -profileName  works on Unix.

However, like the WAS uninstall script - there is file system residue that must be addressed manually.  In my case the profile named folders were still in place with just the log folder and subordinate files in them.